# Save fields when creating user?

Tags: 7, hooks, users

I've added some custom fields in "Account Settings" at *admin/config/people/accounts/fields*. But, those doesn't appear on the "Add user" menu on *admin/people*, and appear on user edit page *user/%uid/edit*.
I need to have them on the account creation page too. By using `hook_form_alter()` I can add the fields on the form. But, I need them to be saved when the user gets created. I understand that fields can be added to a user only on successful creation of the user by `user_save()`. So, I think I need to write a validation (after successful user creation) to save the fields for the newly created user. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field should be visible if you check the checkbox which says: **Display on user registration form.** on *admin/config/people/accounts/fields/FIELD* near the top.

If you don't want the field on the standard user registration form which is visible to visitors, you could always use `hook_form_alter()` to hide that field there.

This way, Drupal will handle the validation and saving of the field for you.